# Exception Breakpoints - LLDB Results vs. GDB

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, lldb

I have searched for topics specifically to this question but have not found anything close to my experience. Forgive me if I have overlooked the answer. I am familiar with GDB and exception points, break points, etc... but the following test of debugging in GDB vs LDB left me without a plausible response.

**Global Test Values**

- Xcode 4.2.1
- New Single Window Project (Default template w/no changes)
- Arc Enabled
- Storyboard Enabled

**Case 1 - GDB Debugger**

Exception Breakpoint Values:

- Exception - All
- Break on - Throw
- Arguments - None
- Result - No Crash

**Case 2 - LLDB Debugger**

Exception Breakpoint Values:

- Exception - All
- Break on - Throw
- Arguments - None
- Result - Crash with Sigbart & machine code; no discernible stack trace

**Case 3 - LLDB Debugger**

Exception Breakpoint Values:

- Exception - Objective-C
- Break on - Throw
- Arguments - None
- Result - No Crash

**Case 4 - LLDB Debugger**

Exception Breakpoint Values:

- Exception - C++
- Break on - Throw
- Arguments - None
- Result - Crash with Sigbart and machine code; no discernible stack trace

**Question:** Should I simply assume that selecting "Objective-C" as an Exception option is a safe way to go, or am I potentially ignoring a glaring issue? It is my understanding that as of Xcode 4.2.1, it is recommended I use LLDB and would like to. However, I am curious about the results above.

Thanks in advance to all community responses!

Comment: does it make a difference whether you're running on a device or in the simulator? i seem to recall running into non-objc (ie. c++) exceptions on startup when running in the simulator.

Comment: Thanks @MikeK for the suggestion! You are correct. When reproducing the test on a device, there is no longer a crash when "Exception: All" or "Exception: C++" are selected. I am still curious about why the crash occurs in the simulator for posterity. >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the thoughtful suggestion of **@Mike K**, I was able to address my concern of potentially ignoring a glaring issue.

When I reproduce the above mentioned scenario on an actual device iPhone/iPad, **Cases 2 and 4** using LLDB no longer produce a crash and the application runs as intended. The issue seems to be limited to the simulator.

I am interested in the root cause of the problem on the simulator for posterity's sake, but am quite happy that I can proceed using LLDB as intended.