# With Break On Exception enabled app always breaks in main.m in Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, xcode4.2, lldb

I've added a `Break on Exception` breakpoint as discussed on previous threads and discussed [here](http://ijoshsmith.com/2011/11/28/debugging-exceptions-in-xcode-4-2/) so that my app will break at the relevant place in my code when an exception happends but now every time I launch the app, Xcode breaks instantly in main.m at this line:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

No error message is displayed or shown in the log the only log output is `(lldb)`.

The app does not appear to have crashed and the app does not crash or break at this line if I remove the Break on Exception rule.

I'm using the LLDB debugger and Automatic Reference Counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I switched to LLDB. I switched back to GDB and this fixed it. Not ideal but works. See this post: [Exception Breakpoints - LLDB Results vs. GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997547/exception-breakpoints-lldb-results-vs-gdb)

Have you tried running on the device with LLDB and Break on Exception?

Comment: Bingo, it works when I switched back to GDB. Seems odd that this would not work using LLDB and is not documented.